Disable Internet access but allow chrome extension
I'm trying to deny access to the Internet and that part works with ufw default deny outgoing (the PC is going to be used for exams so no googling allowed;-))
But
I need access to a chrome extension called AppWriter (reads up the tests in PDF)
Should that be possible or is it a complete no go?
Thanks

You can look up what sites your extension needs access to, then whitelist those domains.

This is the extension:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/appwriter-cloud/lokadhdaghfjbmailhhenifjejpokche?hl=da&utm_source=ext_sidebar
I have used wireshark to look for IPs but how would you go whitelistening those?

You may want to ask the creator of the Chrome extension about off line access, and which site it requires access to, to work. Once you have that information, adjust the ufw rule accordingly.

You can use iptables or other firewall tools to disable all network access to Chrome, and then add the domain name or IP rules used by the extension to achieve this effect.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install iptables


sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d example.com -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d IP -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s example.com -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IP -j ACCEPT

If you want persistence
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Make sure the iptables rules are restored on reboot
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload

Verify the rules
sudo iptables -L -v


Thanks. The "sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP" sure drops connections but the accept part doesn't seem to allow trafic?!?
Is it neccesary to make it persistence and reboot for it to work?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
